# How to create web.config URL Rewrite to redirect a subdomain to a pageroute

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I want to create a rewrite rule on web.config like subdomain.domain.com to www.domain.com/abc/xyz and keep the url subdomain.domain.com on browser bar.
How can I do that? I tried a lot of configurations but seems that this is not possible.

Below is a example that i tried:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SubDomain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\w+)\.domain\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.domain.com.com/abc/xyz" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<rule name="SubDomain" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*).domain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/abc/xyz" />
</rule>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the page /abc/xyz will try to open all relative content as subdomain.domain.com/style.css for example.
I solve the problem by change all content references as absolute URLs.
Thanks for you help.